# PHP problem decoding GET parameter with double quotes

Tags: php, json, decode

I'm passing a 'data' parameter to a php page using AJAX. The parameter is a JSON string like:

```
{"type":"value"}
```

I encode with encodeURIComponent JS function getting:

```
%7B%22type%22%3A%22value%22%7D
```

If I write by hand:

```
http://some_url/index.php?data=%7B%22type%22%3A%22value%22%7D
```

my "index.php" simply gets the parameters and "prints in the screen". The problem is I'm getting this which isn't a valid JSON to decode:

```
{\"type\":\"value\"}
```

Any help,
thanks in advance

Comment: So `{\"type\":\"value\"}` is what you get when you do `echo $_GET['echo']` ? Have you tried to use `json_decode`?

Answer (score 2):

Check that you don't have [magic_quotes](https://www.php.net/magic_quotes) on. The use json_decode() to decode your JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this. Replace de "\" from the parameter.

```
$jsonString = $_GET['data'];

$jsonStringReplaced = str_replace("\\","",$jsonString);

$arr = json_decode($jsonStringReplaced);

var_dump($arr);
```

It worked for me.